# Convexitiy of multi-class hinge loss

Tags: svm, convex

The empirical risk of a multi-class hinge-loss is given by

$$L(\Theta,(x,y) = \max_{j \neq y} \Big[1+ \sum_{i=1}^{d} x_i(\Theta_{ij} - \Theta_{iy}) \Big]_{+} $$

where $x \in \mathbb{R}^{d}$ is a feature vector, $y \in \{0,\dots,9 \} $ is a label vector and $\Theta \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times 10}$ is the classifier. The empirical risk function we aim to minimize is:

$$R^{\text{emp}}(\Theta) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} L(\Theta, (x_k,y_k)).$$

I need to

- Show that $R^{\text{emp}}(\Theta)$ is convex.

One approach I'm thinking about is finding an expression for the Hessian, $H_{ij} = \frac{\partial^2L}{\partial x_i x_j}$ is positive semidefinite. Don't know if this is the most keen way.

- Provide an expression for a subgradient $G$ of $ R^{\text{emp}}(\Theta) $.

Any tips?

Comment: The Hessian you mention is w.r.t. $x$. Are you sure about that? I suppose convexity in $\Theta$ is what you are looking for.

Comment: That's true, since $R^{emp}$ is a function of $\Theta$. How would a derivative look w.r.t to a matrix?

Comment: You compute the partial derivative w.r.t. all components in the same way you do it for any function on $\mathbb{R}^d$